# How to install zlib libgcrypt using apt-get?

Tags: software-installation

When I do `dpkg -i`

I see `zlibc` and `libgcrypt11` in the installed applications' list.
But when I compile a c program having `<zlib.c>` or `<gcrypt.c>` it gives this error:

```
no such file or directory
```

Are they really installed? Or they need to be added in gcc's path? If so what is the path of there header files?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When compiling you also need the development files, such as header files, for the required libraries. These generally live in separate packages. In this case that translates into you also needing the packages `libgcrypt11-dev` and `zlib1g-dev`.

Comment: andol, You simply Rock !!! Thanks man that worked and compiled nicely !!!
So generally `-dev` is for the header files(and other needful files)